# Flutter: trying to mock the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` but throws error?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to write some tests and I need to mock the given function but the test throws this error:

`Failed to load "/Users/.../IdeaProjects/.../myapp/test/helper_functions_test.dart": MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider_macos)`

While I have this code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

setUpAll(() {
  const channel = MethodChannel(
    'plugins.flutter.io/path_provider_macos',
  );
  channel.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
    switch (methodCall.method) {
      case 'getApplicationDocumentsDirectory':
        return "PATH_TO_MOCK_DIR";
      default:
    }
  });
});

...my tests

}
```

But no change. Appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your function body - `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`

And another solution would be to use `'plugins.flutter.io/path_provider'`